# How can I make vertically scrollable textview in remoteviews of a widget?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, textview, android-remoteview

Hi I am a newbie in android development and confused about **how to make TextView in a widget (remoteviews) scrollable**. I have add `android:scrollbars="vertical"` in attributes 
 of `TextView`, however, it makes no response when I touch it.
Can any one please tell me how to solve this, thanks a lot.

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.loli.net/2018/10/26/5bd30e22df511.png).

Here is the [code](https://i.loli.net/2018/10/26/5bd30e236f1ba.png).

Comment: It might be tricky as it's a RemoteView and not all the attributes of the normal Views work. I would try having the TextView as a single element of a ListView and populate that with a RemoteViewsService (See the ['Using App Widgets with Collections'](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#collections))

It is not meant to be used like that, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To make textview text scrollable you can use **ScrollView** widget like this

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
  <Your TextView Code/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this example

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:maxLines = "3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"></TextView>
```

> In java,

```
TextView txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    String text="your text";
    txtview.setText(text);
    txtview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I get the TextView from the RemoteViews Object? I can only get the view of the widget via RemoteViews now.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have a reference to your TextView, now you can try this:

```
TextView nameOfYourTextView = findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_text_view);    
nameOfYourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I am not clear how can I get the TextView from the RemoteViews object...